# How can I import an iDVD project into DVD Studio Pro?

Tags: idvd, dvd-studio-pro

I don't know if this is even possible, but how can I import an iDVD project into DVD Studio Pro? I really want to be able to copy an iDVD project and tweak it in DVDSP.

I am using DVDSP 4.2.2 and iDVD 7.1.2.

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://www.rippletraining.com/importing_idvd_into_dvdsp.html) seems to be a way to go about it, but this only seems to work for iDVD 4.0 or earlier.

I'm not sure how relevant this is to you though, because I don't know the versions of the software you are using.

I have zero experience working with iDVD but maybe it is possible to save your project in an older format / convert it to an older format, to make sure it can be imported.

Comment: Updated question to add version numbers.

Comment: So it looks like I can only import projects from iDVD 4.0 or earlier. Thanks for your help, but I don't have iDVD 4. Too bad. :-(